# Parameter passing for the username field using one url

Tags: php, html, parameter-passing

I want to insert one link in the email for example:

https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym&.intl=us

When user click on that link button in email then this yahoo login page should open in the default browser, it's very simple to do but I want that one predefined username should also insert in the username field.

How can I pass username as parameter for username field?

Thanks

Comment: Unless yahoo supports sending the username as a query parameter then its not possible

Comment: Yahoo was an example. I can use any other web application login screen. I tried with Selenium, I capture till login and enter username in the field. Later I replace that username with php variable. I put that script on server and tried to call it using one link button but it didn't work because selenium script only runs in selenium environment. I was wondering that which tool should I use to write script which should execute when user click button in email? javascript?